# get p tag text in jquery for ajax live search

Tags: jquery, ajax, livesearch

Hello I have a live search, I send data with ajax and get result search and I can show my result, my result shown in P tag, I wanna access to P tag text in my result search but I cant. please help me

```
$.ajax({
        url:'<?=base_url();?>report/Chanel/search',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#DateForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data == "0")
            {
               $('#livesearch').html('not found any result');
            }
            else
            {
                var dataPo = [];
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    $('#livesearch').append('<p class="ppppp" id="pppp'+i+'">'+obj[i]["channel"].Group_Channel_Name+'</p>')
                    $("#pppp"+i).click(function(){alert($("#pppp"+i).text())});
                 }

            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("try again");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the "p" and add the event. Finally, append it to liveSearch.

```
  var obj = [{
  "name": "Ford",
  id: 1
}, {
  "name": "BMW",
  id: 2
}, {
  "name": "Fiat",
  id: 3
}];

$.each(obj, function(index, element) {
  var p = $('<p id="ppp' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</p>');
  p.click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text());

  });

  $('#livesearch').append(p)

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ua2buz9t/3/

Comment: Not work this code, how I can use var element = $("<p>here</p>"); in FOR with different p tag text